# Is outlining non rectangular objects on a website possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a type of map that outlines certain areas when an element is hovered on. So basically I want certain countries to get outlined, or even filled. Is there any possible way to do this, perhaps with javascript/query?

Comment: You can do it with svg.

Comment: SVG would be the ideal way to do this I believe. There may be some way to achieve this with sprite images, but the hover area from an image map will always be square, I think.

Comment: What kind of maps are you looking to create? Google Maps has this functionality built into the API.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at raphaeljs - a javascript SVG library. Here is an example that does exactly what you're talking about: http://raphaeljs.com/world/

Comment: This looks extremely complicated without copying his code. Also I need it to basically only have Southeast Asia and perhaps each country to be broken up, like puzzle pieces..